# WiFi keeps disconnecting

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, 15.04

My wireless connection keeps randomly disconnecting. Sometimes it connects back after few seconds, and sometimes not.

Sometimes I have to run `sudo service network-manager restart`, otherwise it won't reconnect until system reboot.

I've faced this problem on both Ubuntu 14.04.3 and Ubuntu 15.04.

The following is a result from `iwconfig`, my WiFi card is: **Ralink RT5390**.

```
IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"BTHub5-J27X"  
Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 00:84:B0:EB:E5:E8   
Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
Power Management:off
Link Quality=65/70  Signal level=-45 dBm  
Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
Tx excessive retries:32  Invalid misc:60   Missed beacon:0


uname -r
3.19.0-28-generic


lspci
03:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe

lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:5390]
Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:1155]
Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
```

Furthermore, the connection on my Android device is stable.

Your help is very appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: I think this may be a driver problem.I wonder it will be helpful when you update the latest kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Ive seen disconnects being caused by faulty power saving capabilities of the driver/chip

To quickly check if this is the case

try:

```
 sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

and see if you see any difference.
Make note that this will not change your settings permanently.
So they will be reset on suspend & reboot

Answer (score 0):

This is a hardware level problem . Probably your wireless chip can't catch the frequencies properly . I had a similar issue . you probably have to dissemble your device . There is two plug connected with the wireless chip . Check if they are ok . If they are then try disconnecting them . before disconnecting please remember which one is connected to which socket . then reconnect them . see if it works . If it doesn't then probably your wireless lan is faulty . you have to replace it with new one .

Answer (score 0):

try switching the **driver** (from `rt2800pci`) to **`rt2860sta`**, see [here](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Ralink_RT5390_Reference_Design) and [here](https://superuser.com/a/757483).

<sub>if that doesn't help, might need to check/update firmware (e.g. `# apt-get update && apt-get install firmware-ralink`.</sub>

Comment: This may work, also the firmware upgrade too. Please elaborate how to do the switch.

Comment: There is not package `firmware-ralink`.

Comment: re driver: this might help http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1937572

Comment: @Pilot6 are you sure? https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/rt73

Comment: I am sure. We are not on Debian.